# Numpy: efficient array of indices to "bump" array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

Given a length `n` array of indices in `0 ... k-1` (i.e. `A = [0, 0, 1, 2, 1, ...]`), what is the most efficient way to form a new array of shape `(n, k)` `B`, such that `B[i,j] = 1` if `A[i] == j` and `A[i] = 0` otherwise?

i.e, for the example `A = [0, 0, 1, 2, 1, ...]` `(k=3)`, we would get

`B = [[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], ...]`

Is there a way to do this without an explicit for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the sparsity of the array that you build, you might want to use Scipy's sparse matrices, which have the advantage of having a small memory footprint:

```
import numpy
from scipy import sparse

A = numpy.array([0, 0, 1, 2, 1])
k = 3
B = sparse.coo_matrix((numpy.full(len(A), 1, dtype=int), (numpy.arange(len(A)), A)), shape=(len(A), k))
```

(`coo_matrix()` is described in [Scipy's documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.coo_matrix)). This gives the intended result:

```
>>> B.todense()
matrix([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  0.]])
```

but with a small memory footprint (if `k` is large enough [larger than a few units]). In order to save even more memory, the `dtype` above could be made smaller (depending on your exact needs), with `dtype=numpy.int8` or even `dtype=bool`.

Comment: Your point about memory is valid, and holds true for very sparse matrices (large k in this case). However, one must be careful. In the above example, dtype could be `int8`, while dtype of rows and cols of sparse matrix is `int32` (enlighten me we can change that). For our small example, dense matrix takes up 15 bytes, while sparse 45 bytes, data : 5 bytes, rows: 20 bytes, cols: 20 bytes. In OP's case if k > 9 than sparse would save memory.

Comment: Good point. I added a caveat about the relationship between the memory footprint and the value of `k`.

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([0, 0, 1, 2, 1])

B = np.zeros((len(A), 3), dtype=np.int)

B[np.arange(len(A)), A] = 1
```

Result:

```
>>> B
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A=np.array([0, 0, 1, 2, 1])
n=5
k=3
B=np.zeros(n*k, 'int')
B[np.arange(n)*k+A]=1
B.reshape((n,k))
```

result:

```
array([[ 1,  0,  0],
       [ 1,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  1],
       [ 0,  1,  0]])
```

Comment: This works but this is unnecessarily convoluted, as Akavall's answer shows (NumPy offers the ability to assign values at specific 2D coordinates, so good code should use it, since it makes it way easier/faster to read).